# How to live display webcam of players in Unity? (I tried with Photon)

Tags: unity-game-engine, video-streaming, photon

I am trying to make a multiplayer game  where each player has their webcam displayed in the face of their avatar. I am getting the null reference exception: object reference not set to an instance of an object. The following code is attached to a quad in which the webcam output that was
converted to jpeg should be displayed. Any help would be appreciated.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;

public class photonwebcam : MonoBehaviour
{  
    WebCamTexture webcamTexture;
    PhotonView photonView;

    void Start()
    {    
        PhotonView photonView = PhotonView.Get(this);
        if (!webcamTexture.isPlaying)
        {
            webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
            Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
            renderer.material.mainTexture = webcamTexture;
            webcamTexture.Play();

        }
    
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {   
        
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(webcamTexture.width, webcamTexture.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        tex.SetPixels(webcamTexture.GetPixels());
        tex.Apply();
        byte[] bytes = tex.EncodeToJPG();
        photonView.RPC("VideoToBytes", RpcTarget.AllBuffered, bytes);
        Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets();
        
    }

    [PunRPC]
    public void VideoToBytes(byte[] bytes)
    {   
        if (bytes!= null)
        {
            Texture2D texa = new Texture2D(2, 2);
            // Load data into the texture.
            texa.LoadImage(bytes);
            // Assign texture to renderer's material.
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = texa;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem that will give you NullPointerException is that in Start you create a local variable photonView, instead of assigning the field. 
The problem with this approach is that RPC is not optimized for large data, so the image will be laggy. 
I think you can use [Agora](https://docs.agora.io/en) instead of RPC to handle webcam sharing.